# printk loglevel usage in module programming

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, printk

In the book [LDD3 by Rubini](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/), under the `printk` section the author says that we can give log levels/priority to our messages. But I tried with a simple module program having different log-level of printks but it showing the same order in which I have written the printk message inside the program, why it is not printing according to the priority?

I have copied the code here

```
  #include<linux/module.h>
  #include<linux/kernel.h>
  static __init int log_init(void)
     {
         printk(KERN_INFO"inside init 4 \n");
         printk(KERN_ERR"inside init 3\n");
         printk(KERN_CRIT"inside init 2\n");

         return 0;
     }
  static __exit void log_exit(void)
    {
        printk("inside exit\n");
    }
  module_init(log_init);
  module_exit(log_exit);

  MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

And I got a output as follows

```
[ 1508.721441] inside init 4 
[ 1508.721448] inside init 3
[ 1508.721454] inside init 2
root@jitesh-desktop:~/DD/debug/print#
```

so how I can print it according to priority like

```
init 2
init 3
init 4
```

Answer (score 11):

You are confusing the purpose of the `printk` priorities. They are not meant to change the order of execution as you are wishing here.

By assigning different priorities to different kernel messages, ***we can filter out the desired messages that appear on the console by specifying an appropriate value of `loglevel` through the kernel command line***. For example, in the linux kernel. there are numerous messages with `KERN_DEBUG` priority. These are just ordinary debugging messages. So if you enable `loglevel` to the maximum 7, then you'll see a flood of messages on the console!! And your vital errors and warnings will be buried under this flurry of normal debugging messages.

So when you are debugging serious issues, you can specify the `loglevel` to a low value so that only critcal errors and warnings are displayed on the console.

**Note**: Irrespective of the `loglevel`, all `printk` messages are stored in the kernel buffer. The priority decides which one of them goes to the console.

Comment: Also: you can change the log level dynamically by writing it to `/proc/sys/kernel/printk`, e.g. `echo 3 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk`. `cat`ing this file will show you, in the following order: current level, default level for messages without a warning, minimum level and boot time default level.